# Is it possible to complete a StackOverflow Careers profile?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I have spent ages building up a Stack Overflow Careers profile but it sits at 98% complete, demanding I provide 3 links to articles/books I have written.

I have not got 3 published works or blogs I have written that I can link to. Am I somehow excluded because of this?  How do I complete my profile?

**Edit**

The "My Profile" page clearly states:

> Unlock your profile: By completing your profile, you can access additional Careers features.

I don't see how writing 3 blogs should be a requirement for me to access those "additional features"

On the "Profile Settings" page it says:

> "Your profile is currently private."

and has a **disabled** button:

> "Make my profile public".

Assuming this button becomes enabled when I complete my profile, does this mean that my profile is unable to be seen until I write 3 blogs?

It also states:

> "Your profile is currently blocking all search engines."

with another disabled button. Am I not allowed to share my profile to prospective employers unless I write 3 blog posts?

This seems like madness to me.

Comment: AFAIK, it's really just a guideline, and nobody sees it but you.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara But you see it, and it will bug you _forever_

Comment: I think you're wrong about needing it to be 100% complete. Mine is only 79% complete and I can make it public if I want. Have you added any entry into the text box as shown?  http://i.stack.imgur.com/fyKxl.png

Comment: @MartinSmith ah!  you are correct, good sir!  This would be a good candidate for some disabled-button-hover-text I think...  Thank you :)

Comment: I think it should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @MartinSmith: good comment, seems to solve the problem. It is now an answer. Post your own and reply to this to delete the cw-one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [comment by @MartinSmith:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310820/is-it-possible-to-complete-a-stackoverflow-careers-profile#comment274456_310820)

> I think you're wrong about needing it to be 100% complete. Mine is only 79% complete and I can make it public if I want. Have you added any entry into the text box as shown? [i.stack.imgur.com/fyKxl.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyKxl.png)